# Open email intent and send screen shot

Tags: android, email, android-studio, android-intent

I have a function that I want to take a screen shot of the current activity and allow me to send it as an email.

```
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        File filelocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), mPath);
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filelocation);

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        // set the type to 'email'
        emailIntent .setType("message/rfc822");
        String to[] = {"xxx@outlook.com"};
        emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        // the attachment
        emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
        // the mail subject
        emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send yourself your journey......"));
```

It doesn't seem to be taking the screenshot and when I open the email prompt I get the following message. "All apps associated with this action have been disabled, blocked, or are not installed"

I'm using a Samsung s8 as my test device just incase that makes a difference and I have all permissions granted to my application.